# How access SQL values in a Group clause with an Mysqli Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, group-by, clause

I'm trying run a prepared statement using mysqli.

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(authors.author_id,' ', first_name,' ', last_name))
FROM books, authors, books_authors
WHERE books.book_id = books_authors.book_id 
AND authors.author_id = books_authors.author_id 
GROUP BY books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail");

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail, $author_id);
```

All the values are displayed correctly except for the author names. The author names aren't displayed at all. The first_name, and last_name fields are in a `GROUP BY` clause in the `SQL`. How do I access those values in the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` without getting an error of the number of `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` fields not matching the `mysqli_stmt_prepare`?

I'm fetching the results in a while loop with

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
```

Comment: I would suggest you to avoid `FROM a lot of tables` and use `JOIN`s instead.

Comment: Could you provide your tables structure, please?

Comment: Also, your usage of `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` function is incorrect. Check here how to correctly use it: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this may help you

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(authors.author_id,' ', first_name,' ', last_name))
FROM books, authors, books_authors
WHERE books.book_id = books_authors.book_id 
AND authors.author_id = books_authors.author_id 
GROUP BY books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail");

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, books.book_id, title, publish_date, thumbnail, $author_id);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }
```